# How to compile the cython modules for gensim?

Tags: gensim

Is there a standard process that [gensim](https://github.com/rare-technologies/gensim) uses to compile the cython bits?  I've forked the project and edited the cython code, but it doesn't seem to recompile when I run `python3 setup.py install --force`.

I'm not getting any errors, it just doesn't seem to even attempt to compile the cython code.  I have a [fresh clone of the `develop` branch](https://github.com/rare-technologies/gensim)

How do I compile gensim "from source"?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
gcc: 5.4.0

Comment: What OS are you using, and are the OS's c-compilation tools installed? Are you using a virtual environment? Are you seeing any errors when you try that `install` command? How are you monitoring for the success of the compilation/install?

Comment: @gojomo, I had edited some lines of cython code to try and get gensim to accept an array for `alpha`, the train rate.  However, when I `setup.py install --force`, I don't see an c-compiling-type-output in the console.  Also, I get the same tracebacks complaining about `alpha` can't be an array on the same lines I just changed.  They are unchanged in the traceback.  However, if I change `python` bits, then they get updated when I `setup.py install --force`.  So gensim is installing itself, it's just not recompiling the cython.

Comment: Using the `build_ext` command, for example `python ./setup.py build_ext --inplace` before trying an `install`, *might* do the trick, or at least generate some new more-helpful errors. Some of my notes on tinkering with the cython files incrementally in a local/editable gensim source installation are in the project form message: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gensim/LTdrGBysMyw/e9-WETojDQAJ